# cannot give larger input in a program

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a question on codechef. This code is running fine as far as logic is considered, but I am having trouble with giving large inputs.
For example, if I give input of 13 or more digits then it does not run in vscode, and if the input is 22 digits or more then it does not run in devc++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    int t, l, i, flag = 0;
    char ch = ' ';
    scanf("%d", &t);
    char d[t][100000];
    int out[t];

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &d[t]);
        size_t len = strlen(d[t]);
        printf("\n%d", len);
        char ch = d[t][0];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if ((ch != d[t][j])) {
                flag++;
            }
        }
        if (flag >= 2 && flag != (len-1))
            out[i]=0;
        else
            out[i]=1;
        flag = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        if (out[i] == 1)
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

TEST RUN 1:-

```
1
11110111111
11
Yes
```

TEST RUN 2:-

```
1
111101111111
0
```

Why doesn't it handle larger inputs?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&d[t]);`. I guess you mean `scanf("%s",d[i]);` That said, useless to use a 2D array, the cases are treated independently.

Comment: ... and three other uses of the array.

Comment: @Damien doesn't matter I am taking a new string each time storing it in d[t] and storing output for it in an array...so changing it to d[i] doesn't changes anything

Comment: That depends on how large `t` is. `char d[t][100000];` can break the stack, and it isn't even necessary (nor `out[]`).

Comment: `d[t]` corresponds to an out-of-bound access. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Given that you scan the whole string only once, you don't need an array at all.

Comment: "taking a new string each time storing it in d[t] " --> to store in `d[t]` is invalid if `t` is 1, 10 or 100.

Comment: Thanks guys I got the error but still I can't understand how it was working fine with smaller inputs and why wasn't compiler giving error??

Comment: `char d[t][100000]` is probably too big for a local variable. Try `char d[t][10000]`, but anyway as already pointed out in other comments the array isn't necessary

Comment: methead, When you do the wrong this like `scanf("%s", &d[t])`, the program is not required to error.  Might "work", might not.  Research _undefined behavior_.

Comment: "I can't understand how it was working fine with smaller inputs" – that's the nature of *undefined behaviour*. It might work, it might not, it might crash, and so on.

Comment: And do not forget to copy at least 10 times *UB can lead to **any** behaviour*...

Answer (score 0):

When you start writing from `d[t]`, you are out of the bounds of the array, meaning that you might be overwriting other parts of your program. You should instead write to `d[i]`.

Also this array is now on the stack, but the stack only has a very limited size, so there is a high risk you might go over that size, which is called a stack overflow. On windows the stack size is I think 1MB, so if `t` was bigger than 10 you would already exceed that. So you should allocate on the heap instead.

This should work, but I did not test it:

```
int t = 0;

scanf("%d", &t);
char **d = (char **)malloc(t * sizeof(char *));

for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
    d[i] = (char *)malloc(STR_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", d[i]);
}
```